# How to record custom performance metrics with GCP Monitoring from python3 apps

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm working on decorator that can be added to python methods that send a metric to GCP Monitoring.  The approach is confirmed but the API calls to push the metrics fail if I attempt to send more than 1 observation.  The patter is collect metrics and flush after the process finishes to keep it simple for this test.  The code to capture the metric inline is here:

```
    def append(self, value):
        now = time.time()
        seconds = int(now)
        nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
        interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
            {"end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos}}
        )
        point = monitoring_v3.Point({
            "interval": interval,
            "value": {"double_value": value}
            }
        )
        self.samples[self.name].append(point)
```

The code below takes a batch of data points in `PerfMetric.samples` dict pointing to arrays of the `monitoring_v3.Point` class which was attached in the method `append` via a decorator not shown here to call RPC called create_time_series using the `MetricServiceClient` class.  We point to an array of arrays, so perhaps that's not right or somehow our meta data isn't right in append?

```
 @staticmethod
 def flush():
     client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
     for x in PerfMetric.samples:
         print('{} has {} points'.format(x, len(PerfMetric.samples[x])))
         series = monitoring_v3.TimeSeries()
         series.metric.type = 'custom.googleapis.com/perf/{}'.format(x)
         series.resource.type = "global"
         series.points = PerfMetric.samples[x]
         client.create_time_series(request={
             "name": PerfMetric.project_name,
             "time_series": [series]}
         )
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a documented limitation in the [TimeSeries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/TimeSeries) call from the Cloud Monitoring API regarding the `points[]` object for its data points:

> When creating a time series, this field must contain **exactly one point** and the point's type must be the same as the value type of the associated metric.